# i have angular JS form it is inserting data successfully into database but not showing in table listing below the form

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have an HTML form that is inserting successfully data into a database, but is not showing the data in the table below it. The only way to check we have to use is to manually refresh the page. The same happen with delete, sometimes a dialog is shown, telling us that value was deleted, but we still have two referesh the page to see the change.
Is there any fucntion to reload that listing?
Any help would be appreciated

Here is my angular html Named as : manage_features.html

```html
<!-- START panel-->
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                         <h3>Manage Features Name</h3>
                      </div>
                     <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                              <div class="col-lg-10">
                                 <input type="text" ng-model="rec.Name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
                              </div>
                           </div>
                          
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                 <div class="checkbox c-checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="rec.isSpecial">
                                       <span class="fa fa-check"></span>is Special</label>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                 <div class="checkbox c-checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="rec.isMultiple">
                                       <span class="fa fa-check"></span>Is Multiple</label>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>


                           <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                 <button type="button" ng-click="add(rec)" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">ADD</button>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </form>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- END panel-->
```

here is my JS file named as manage_features.js

```js
$scope.add = function(rec){
 console.log(rec);
$scope.upload = $upload.upload({
   url: 'api/AdminArea/feature/add', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url 
   method: 'POST', 
   headers: {'header-key': '83c238df1650bccb2d1aa4495723c63f07672ee8'}, 
   withCredentials: true, 
   data:{data:rec},
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     console.log(data);
     return false;

      toaster.pop('success', 'Add', 'Record added successfully.');
      $scope.$root.$broadcast("myDocEventReload", {});
      
    });


};
```

here is delete function

```js
$scope.delete = function (id) {
 console.log(id);//return false;
    ngDialog.openConfirm({
      template: 'modalDeleteDialogId',
      className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
    }).then(function (value) {
      $http
    .post('api/AdminArea/feature/delete', {id:id})
    .then(function (res) {
     console.log(res.data);
    if(res.data != 1){
     toaster.pop('success', 'Deleted', 'Record deleted successfully.');

     
    }
    else{
     toaster.pop('error', 'Deleted', 'Record can\'t be deleted!');
     
    }
    });
    }, function (reason) {
      console.log('Modal promise rejected. Reason: ', reason);
    });
 
 //if(popupService.showPopup('Would you like to delete?')) {
  
 //  }
 };
```

Comment: After save/delete data in to DB call `$route.reload()` in your controller it refreshes the view.

Comment: thanx for reply let me try

Comment: Don't forget to inject $route in your controller.

Comment: @che will u please send some example code ?

Comment: Where you getting data from the db after saving new record or after delete operation? Is the issue only with view or with data too ?

Comment: It will help us if you create a plunker for this problem with dummy data.

Comment: Actually i geting data from php function which is ok

Comment: I think your is not the best way to use angularjs, it can be very powerful if used as it wants to be used. I would wrap the functions in a controller, handle the html with it, I think it should be easier.

Answer (score 0):

The main point, that I can basically see in your code, is that the object 'rec' is used 'freely' and for this reason when you receive the response from the server you are not populating the correct object.

The reason for this is that when you are calling `.then(function (res) {` the 'res' variable is confined in the scope of that particular function, and won't change the value of the scope variable.

my advice is to do something like this:

create a controller

```
angular.module('mymodule',[]).controller('myCtrl',['$upload','toaster' function($upload, toaster){
    var self = this;
    self.rec = {};

    self.add = function(){
        $upload.upload({
        url: 'api/AdminArea/feature/add', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url 
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {'header-key': '83c238df1650bccb2d1aa4495723c63f07672ee8'}, 
        withCredentials: true, 
        data:{data:self.rec},
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        /* THIS RETURN WAS BLOCKING THE NEXT, YOU HAVE TO REMOVE IT
        console.log(data);
        return false;*/

                 toaster.pop('success', 'Add', 'Record added successfully.');
                 /*$scope.$root.$broadcast("myDocEventReload", {});*/

      });
    }

    self.delete = function(id){
        console.log(id);//return false;
        ngDialog.openConfirm({
            template: 'modalDeleteDialogId',
            className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
        }).then(function (value) {
            $http
                .post('api/AdminArea/feature/delete', {id:id})
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    if(response.data != 1){
                        toaster.pop('success', 'Deleted', 'Record deleted successfully.');


                    }
                    else{
                        toaster.pop('error', 'Deleted', 'Record can\'t be deleted!');

                    }
                });
        }, function (reason) {
            console.log('Modal promise rejected. Reason: ', reason);
        });
     };
}
```

Then you can use this controller in your code with

```
<div ng-controller='myCtrl as c'>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="c.rec.isMultiple">
</div>
```

When you change the object rec inside the controller the changes will be visible automatically in the html.

It's a simple answer to tell you the idea of what I think you should do with angular.